# Require a link to the question it is a duplicate of

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

When people vote to close a question, and more importantly when it is closed, a link to the duplicate question should be displayed in all cases.

This should one, reduce the number of claims of "exact duplicate", should the voters fail to agree on which one the question is a duplicate of.  Two, this will allow those of us encountering the question to go an find the answer(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is.

When you vote to close a comment is added with the link to the question you picked.

When the question is closed this is converted into an edit on the question (for example):

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [In the absense of a CS degree, how can I &ldquo;fill in the gaps&rdquo; so to speak?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81591/in-the-absense-of-a-cs-degree-how-can-i-fill-in-the-gaps-so-to-speak)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

[image]

This can be edited out (either maliciously or by accident). If you see a closed as a duplicate question without this text check the revision history and edit it back in.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145784/how-to-be-a-successful-programmer-without-a-cs-degree/145789#145789 doesn't seem to have one. Although it say possible dupe, I see now, but really how do we go from possible to exact?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - scroll to the top of the page :)

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - the discrepancy between the close dialog text and the text that gets inserted has been brought up on MSO before. I wouldn't hold my breath over it being changed now.

Comment: So the answer is, it must have been edited out when I hit the question?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - Possibly. Though there's no history beyond it being automatically added. You might have been seeing a cached version?

Comment: That is also possible, thank you for your assistance.